# how to check If my app still has access to client account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using gmail `api` to `read users mailbox` and `show them on my app`.In order to do that I save his credentials in a `db` which I pass with every `api request to gmail.`

But If the user has removed the access to `my app` as mentioned here **[https://myaccount.google.com/permissions]**    `I would not be able to read his mailbox`, `I get "Error: invalid_grant".`

**my question is how do I check whether I app has access to that account or not using api ?**

Comment: You have to check Scope , if scope not found then you need to authorize user's account again with require scope permission

Comment: can you explain with a nodejs example,I tried but couldn't figure out.Thanks

Comment: If users removed his account , you need to authorize again users account as you did first time, then you will get clientId, Secret key and refresh Token after that only you are able to access his account

Answer (score 0):

Source https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    var readline = require('readline');
    var google = require('googleapis');
    var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json
    var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
    var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
        process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
    var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json';

    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
      // Gmail API.
      authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
    });

    /**
     * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
     * given callback function.
     *
     * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
     * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
     */
    function authorize(credentials, callback) {
      var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
      var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
      var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
      var auth = new googleAuth();
      var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

      // Check if we have previously stored a token.
      fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
          getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
          oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
          callback(oauth2Client);
        }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
     * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
     *
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
     * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
     *     client.
     */
    function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
      var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
      });
      console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
      var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
      });
      rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            return;
          }
          oauth2Client.credentials = token;
          storeToken(token);
          callback(oauth2Client);
        });
      });
    }

    /**
     * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
     *
     * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
     */
    function storeToken(token) {
      try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
          throw err;
        }
      }
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
      console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
    }

    /**
     * Lists the labels in the user's account.
     *
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
     */
    function listLabels(auth) {
      var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
      gmail.users.labels.list({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          return;
        }
        var labels = response.labels;
        if (labels.length == 0) {
          console.log('No labels found.');
        } else {
          console.log('Labels:');
          for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            var label = labels[i];
            console.log('- %s', label.name);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```